# Pyinstaller "No module named xlsxwriter"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

When I used pyinstaller to package my program using the command `pyinstaller --onefile main.py --hidden-import jaraco.windows.api.memory`, and the .exe generates just fine. However, when I try to launch it, it crashes immediately with an error message that says `ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter`.

I saw a previous thread on here where someone had a similar error, however in that thread, the solution was to import it in the script, but I have already done that. On the first line.

The general structure of my program is as follows:
There is a homemade utils library, where some of the items import xlsxWriter.
The main method imports each file in the library

Comment: Can you post your project structure and `setup.py` file?

Comment: Maybe you installed the pip dependencies in a virtual environment, try installing them on your machine's environment if you haven't already.

Comment: @Stress_ I tried having them installed in each of those locations

Comment: @DineshKumar there is no file with that name in the project

Answer (score 0):

Add --hidden-import xlsxwriter to your build command.